# wordpress dropdown menu not working

Tags: wordpress

I have wordpress website created menu from appeareance->menus .  my menu have main menu and sub menu item. some are working and some are not working all menu has same configurations.

[image: i have attached image please have a look]

you can see in above image. first "armut" when i click can just open when i again click could not close. "Kinder / Jugend" working ok. last "archiv" also not working. i have same configured all menus. though getting issue. i am waiting your solution.

sidebar.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The Sidebar containing the main widget area
 */

if ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'page-sidebar' ) ) {
    return;
}
?>
<div class="page-sidebar widget-area" role="complementary">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'page-sidebar' ); ?>
</div><!-- #page-sidebar -->
```

Comment: You need to post the contents of the template file where the menu appears (sidebar.php etc..)

Comment: Did you done any thing in coding? Tell me which theme do you have.

Comment: i have used theme "scalia-default-child" and main theme is "scalia"